# Pro*C: Unable to fetch data from data base

Tags: sql, c

I did a sample code in pro*C language to fetch data from a table.

Table `Emp_table` contain two fields: `Emp_Name` and `EmpId`.

From SQL-Plus I added 3 records and through Pro*C code, added another 3 records.

```
EXEC SQL SELECT Emp_Name INTO :ename From Emp_table where EmpId=1;
```

I'm unable to get the `ename` from the records I added via SQL-Plus but able to get data from records added via Pro*C code.

In SQL-Plus, when I do `select * from Emp_table`, it list all the 6 records.

Can anyone point me if I'm missing anything or it is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not executed commit after insertion of records using SQL*Plus. Can you confirm on this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware about commit after inserting from Sql-plus, new to all this. Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC SQL SELECT [Emp Name] INTO ename From Emp_table where EmpId=1;
```

Comment: Still I'm facing the same issue. Please note that I can read records which i added via Pro*C code. I assume [Emp Name] will consider the field as one parameter. I changed the field as emp_name.